# Which table is used when exists in multiple schema's, but no clarification in SELECT?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find this answer and it is not in any documentation I can find, and I have not attempted to create this and test on our SQL Server as I am afraid this scenario already exists, and I could break some reporting.

Singe table name:

```
Dude
```

Multiple Schemas:

```
dbo.dude
arch.dude
```

If a SELECT statement is ran with no schema, what happens?

```
Select * from Dude;
```

Will a SELECT statement, with existing tables in two Schema's, use the `arch.dude` table in some alphanumeric sort or will it just fail?

I know this is not a "deep" question, but helpful in my quest to instruct others as to why they want to add the schema to the front of their table names in a query.

Comment: It will use the users default schema

Comment: The exact rules are buried in the remarks for [`ALTER USER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks), which is not particularly obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tables created by default in user schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863028/tables-created-by-default-in-user-schema)

Comment: AHiggins: This is a little different as that is discussing creating tables and what default Schema it will use to create the table. I am speaking more from a lower grain of users using SELECT and which schema a table without Schema clarification will chose. dbo or arch or fail.

Comment: Although the docs aren't clear on that *either*, the only schema that will be considered is the user's schema, according to the rules for that (ultimately `dbo` if no more specific schema can be determined). So if the user's schema is not `arch`, then `arch.dude` will never be considered for `SELECT * FROM dude`, even if `dude` only exists in the `arch` schema, and SQL Server never needs to "disambiguate" names based on schemas -- either there's an object with the right name in your default schema, or no match. (Except for stored procedures that start with `sp_`, but that's another matter...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will use the users default schema (which is usually `dbo`). You can change the default like this:

```
ALTER USER SomeUser
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = SomeSchema
```

Or using the SSMS interface:

[image]

Comment: Thanks David. So I assume when a user is created then they are assigned to the default Schema assigned in the Database rules somewhere? Although I can't seem to find it in the DB properties.

Comment: Not quite, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks

Comment: Thanks DavdG. For those that may not see it if power reading, here is an excerpt: 
"If the user has a default schema, that default schema will used. If the user does not have a default schema, but the user is a member of a group that has a default schema, the default schema of the group will be used. If the user does not have a default schema, and is a member of more than one group, the default schema for the user will be that of the Windows group with the lowest principal_id and an explicitly set default schema. If no default schema can be determined for a user, the dbo schema will be used."